# TextBox in .aspx is not accessible in .cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have tried a lot and spent my whole day on it but all in vain. I found number of questions related to my problem but no one is resolving my problem. I have a textbox in Login.aspx with ID="UserName" and trying to get its value in Login.aspx.cs but it gives error that "UserName doesn't exist in current context". here is my Login.aspx (created by default by VS 2012)

```
<%@ Page Title="Log in" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="cpool2.Account.Login" %>  
<%@ Register Src="~/Account/OpenAuthProviders.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="OpenAuthProviders" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <hgroup class="title">
    <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
</hgroup>
<section id="loginForm" runat="server">
    <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
    <asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
            </p>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="checkbox">Remember me?</asp:Label>
                        <%--<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="RegisterHyperLink" NavigateUrl="~/Account/ForgotPassword.aspx" ViewStateMode="Disabled">Forgot Password?</asp:HyperLink>--%>
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log in" OnClick="btnLogin" />
            </fieldset>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
    <p>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="RegisterHyperLink" ViewStateMode="Disabled">Register</asp:HyperLink>
        if you don't have an account.
    </p>
</section>
</asp:Content>
```

Login.aspx.cs is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration; 

namespace cpool2.Account
{
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //protected TextBox UserName;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx";
        OpenAuthLogin.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
        var returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl += "?ReturnUrl=" + returnUrl;
        }   
    }
    protected void btnLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string abc = UserName.Text; // causing error
    }
  }
}
```

I am working in Web Application (asp.net framework 4.5). It may be my silly mistake but it made my day difficult for me :(

Comment: Please check the updated answer, You have to assign an ID to your loginForm to access it in codebehind, However it's very interesting how other answer worked for you without ID. and that's the reason you were getting `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Suraj Singh I used id for <asp:Login> that's why other answers are working, I thought you are using id of <section> which was by chance "loginForm" in my code :)

Comment: It's a typing error i made as i created login control on my system with that ID however if you look at your posted code i didn't see any ID for LoginForm. Please confirm or may be i am wrong.

Comment: I am talking about this <section id="loginForm" runat="server">

Comment: That's what i am saying i made a typing mistake i used `LoginForm` as `<asp:Login ID` , So are you using `SectionID` to find `UserName`  ?

Comment: What i am saying is your code do not contain an `ID` for `loginControl` and i used `loginControl` as ID which happens to be your `sectionID` so it's just a misunderstanding, No problem .

Comment: All confusion was due to that mistake, otherwise your point is valid and same as others. Secondly I am using ``<asp:Login ID`` to find UserName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
TextBox UserName = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
if (UserName != null)
{
    string abc = UserName.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
    first, give id to login control
    <asp:Login id="LoginView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
    </asp:Login>
    then,
    // coding side
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("UserName");
    if (txt != null)
    {
        //access here
    }
```

Hope it helps you.
Thanks.

Comment: Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Answer (score 0):

Give an Id to asp:login control e.g. `ID="LoginUser"` and then you can call like

```
         LoginUser.UserName.Text
```

Comment: or `string abc = (TextBox)LoginUser.FindControl("UserName").Text;`

Comment: @Furqan now it says 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Answer (score 0):

Assign an `ID`  to your `LoginControl` .

```
 <asp:Login runat="server" ID="loginForm" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
```

---

```
 protected void btnLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tbox = this.loginForm.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox;  
            string abc = tbox .Text;

        }
```

Comment: it throws NullReferenceException...however my prob is solved by using this one  TextBox UserName = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
if (UserName != null)
{
    string abc = UserName.Text;
}.....thanks for your reply

Comment: @Rahman For what value you get `NullReferenceException` i do not get it ? You already have a `RequiredFieldValidator` which i think is doing it's work properly. If i am not wrong there is some other problem you may be having with your code.Even if you let `UserName` field empty and disable `RequiredFieldValidator` you will not get any error .Please read about NullReferenceException  here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx

Comment: @Rahman Please check the updated answer, You have to assign an ID to your loginForm to access it in codebehind, However it's very interesting how other answer worked for you without `ID`. and that's the reason you were getting `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I used id for <asp:Login> that's why other answers are working, I thought you are using id of <section> which was by chance "loginForm" in my code :)

Comment: @Rahman It's a typing error i made as i created login control on my system with that `ID` however if you look at your posted code i didn't see any `ID` for `LoginForm`. Please confirm or may be i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change  this

```
<asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
```

to

```
<asp:Login runat="server" id="id_login" RenderOuterTable="false">
```

and get value with

```
id_login.Username
```